# Swift - Server response "unsupported_grant_type"

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to login using alamofire.
im using the following code:

```
let parameters = [
            "username": "2gggggjggg",
            "password": "2ubgh",
        ]
        Alamofire.request(.POST, URL , parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in
            print("request")
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print("response")
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print("data")
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print("result")
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
            print("JSON")
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
            if let myData = response.data?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength) {
                SignUpVC.clientID = myData
                print(myData)
            }
        }
```

the server response as follows:

```
data
Optional(<7b226572 726f7222 3a202275 6e737570 706f7274 65645f67 72616e74 5f747970 65227d>)
result
SUCCESS
JSON
JSON: {
    error = "unsupported_grant_type";
}
```

what might the reason be? am i missing anything?

im new to implementing apps that connects to a server.

as far as i know the server uses Django with REST framework and oAuth2.

i hope to get enough help about it. I've tried to search a lot about this problem and how to resolve it but no luck.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging  check list

1. Did you use https in your url?
2. Did your server have Server Certificate from Certification authority Note iOS 9 will not connected to self sign
   Certificate)?
3. Do you use object maper like "SwiftyJSON" object Model to json

not from the error massage I think you have to check your post url or you Server Certificate

```
let URL:String ="https://youURLHere"
```

Comment: 1-No, just HTTP.  2-We are using AWS so i guess it does. 3- No Im not using any. By the way this code is used to login.

Comment: 400 mean you have bad request from the server side https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Client_error_responses